# Using pass cli for background (cron) jobs securely

Tags: password-management

Q: how to securely use pass tool to for scheduled jobs?

One of the tools to store and manage passwords on a unix machine is [pass](https://www.passwordstore.org/), which is a layer on top of gpg. Any password that I create is encrypted and stored locally, which can be decrypted back again using the private key. Generally, this will require a passphrase to access the private key.

GPG has a cache feature where the passphrase is not required if the same private key were accessed within X minutes. This is a good feature in general.

However, if I want to use pass for a scheduled job (syncing files), then I will need to enter the passphrase each time. I was wondering if there is a way to securely store the password, and at the same time, conveniently access it for such jobs? And what are the implications of such setup?

Comment: Securely storing a password is what a password store is about. In this way you are basically asking how to create a password store which does not require a password. And you want to store inside this store the master password for another password store. I don't think it is a good idea. Instead of exposing all your passwords this way it would be better to get only the sync specific password from the store and protect it outside the store. Or even better create passwords which are only usable for the sync. This way the impact of password compromise is much lower.